# Not getting desired output from inverting Op Amp as adder

Tags: operational-amplifier, inverting-amplifier

Here you can see for an inverting Adder Circuit of Op amp the output is 14.61V but in the second image by solving it using formula I am getting output voltage is 16V why it is happening.

[image]

Here you can see Output is 16V .Here Vi1=-7 ;vi2=5 ;vi3=-7 and feedback resistance is 10K using these values and putting it to the formula of adder circuit I got 16V but in the schematics it is showing around 14.6V i couldn't figure out what is happening here.

[image]

Comment: I remember having similar doubt in school days, if op-amp has 1M open loop gain, why can't I apply 1V and obtain a 1MV !?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using +/-15V rails, the opamp will never go beyond the voltage rails, in fact the opamp you are using will never go to the full voltage rails. Lower the inputs or bump the opamp rails.